# form submission

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

How to specify action to button to submit a form in adobe adobe flex?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) and the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) object.

Your function would look like this: submitForm():void {
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yourURL);
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        vars.yourVar = 'yourValue';
        req.data = vars;
        var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
        ldr.load(req);
    }

and your button would look something like this:

```
<mx:Button label="Submit" click="submitForm();"/>
```

See [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_05.html) for more information.

Comment: i am getting error in this way ....("Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type") what i have to do in order to come out of this?

Comment: i want to load php file form a page by posting a set of inputs from a form that was developed in adobe flex.by giving the above code it is telling loader file has unknown type.how to load php file?

Comment: If the error says that Loader is an invalid type, then you need to add these lines: import flash.events.*; import flash.net.*;